# I am stuck connecting to the internet via a usb wifi stick

Tags: networking, command-line, arch-linux, wifi, ip

I am trying to set up a an internet connection through a usb wifi sticker in Linux.

Here's the sequence I tried:

```
iw dev
```

This returns the name(?) of the Interface that I want to connect to:

```
phy#0
         Interface wlp0s29u1u3
    ....
```

So, I set the variable `i` to that name

```
i=wlp0s29u1u3
```

and try to get the state of that interface:

```
ip link show $i
```

which returns

```
3: wlp0s29u1u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> ....  state DOWN ....
...
```

I try to bring the interface up

```
ip link set $i up
```

This command printed nothing in return.

Again, I do a

```
ip link show $i
```

This time, it prints

```
3: wlp0s29u1u3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> ... state DOWN...
```

Although the state is DOWN, it allows me to scan for wifi points to connect to:

```
iwlist $i scan
```

Indeed, I find "*my*" wifi, with `ESSDI:"foobar"`.

I check if I am connected

```
iw $i link
```

Not surprisingly, I am not:

```
Not connected.
```

So, I try to use `wpa_supplicant` to establish a connection.

First, I store my password for the wifi in the variable `k`:

```
k=secret
```

Then I create the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
wpa_passphrase foobar $k >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And then try to establish the connection:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i $i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

which returns

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

I had assumed that I now shuold be able to use

```
dhclient $i
```

but this command does not return at all.

Also

```
iw $i link
```

still returns

```
Not connected.
```

And

```
ip link show $i
```

shows

```
 3: wlp0s29u1u3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MUTLICAST,UP> .... state DOWN mode DORMANT
```

I am especially unsure about the `NO-CARRIER` part and believe this should be `BROADCAST`.

I have no idea what I should do now.

If I use `wifi-menu -o`, I am able to connect to the wifi (so it seems it's not a hardware problem), but my goal is to go with these `iw` and `ip` command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring up your wifi card:

```
ip link set wlp0s29u1u3 up
```

the output of `ip link show $i` will be:

```
 3: wlp0s29u1u3:  .... state UP
```

Then you can connect using:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i $i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do `ip link set wlp0s29u1u3 up` the output is `....<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>.... state DOWN...`. I have changed my question accordingly.